# PythonQT QGIS print-command

Tags: qgis, pyqt

For debugging purposes I would like to print the content of some variables in my PYGT-function, like:

```
print(myGeometrylength)
```

...

The variable has some content but nothing is printed?

I just get it out by

```
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("blabla", u"blba :"+str(myGeometrylength))
```

Has anybody an idea how to get the print-command working?

Answer (score 1):

It works e.g. in that way:

```
self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Success", "Alles roger in Kambodscha "+str(resultat),level=Qgis.Success, duration=3)
```